# Variable substitution error

Tags: makefile

Does anyone know what is wrong with my Makefile?

```
CXX = g++               # compiler
CXXFLAGS = -g -Wall -MMD        # compiler flags
MAKEFILE_NAME = ${firstword ${MAKEFILE_LIST}} # makefile name

OBJECTS1 = utf.o            # object files forming executable
EXEC1 = utf             # executable name

OBJECTS2 = driver.o rational.o # object files forming executable
EXEC2 = rational            # executable name

OBJECTS3 = da.o qa.o pa.o ua.o # object files forming executable
EXEC3 = ho          # executable name

OBJECTS = ${OBJECTS1} ${OBJECTS2} ${OBJECTS3}
EXECS = ${EXEC1} ${EXEC2} ${EXEC3}
DEPENDS = ${OBJECTS:.o=.d}      # substitute ".o" with ".d"

.PHONY : all clean

all : ${EXECS}

${EXEC1} : ${OBJECTS1}          # link step
    ${CXX} $^ -o $@

${EXEC2} : ${OBJECTS2}          # link step
    ${CXX} $^ -o $@

${EXEC3} : ${OBJECTS3}          # link step
    ${CXX} $^ -o $@

${OBJECTS} : ${MAKEFILE_NAME}       # OPTIONAL : changes to this file => recompile

-include ${DEPENDS}         # include *.d files containing program dependences

clean :                 # remove files that can be regenerated
    rm -f ${DEPENDS} ${OBJECTS} ${EXECS}
```

Error:

```
./Makefile: 1: CXX: not found
./Makefile: 2: CXXFLAGS: not found
./Makefile: 3: Bad substitution
```

Comment: What command line are you using to call your Makefile?

Comment: @jHackTheRipper I am on linux ubuntu 9.something using /xhbin/tcsh

Comment: The error messages give me the impression that you're trying to execute the makefile, rather than invoking `make`.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: that's exactly what I suggested with my question :)

Comment: @Mark: are you doing something like `./Makefile` ? Or are you just typing `make` instead?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth yes I used ./Makefile please point the right method

Comment: I test it on Ubuntu 11, with Bash, and I'm not get that errors

Comment: @Mark: Just type `make` from within the directory where the makefile is located. Have you read any tutorials before coming here? It seems you are just throwing a strangers makefile at us that you have not even tried to understand (I guess so because that example seems non-trivial, and it is unlikely that someone who wrote that makefile would really fail on invoking make)

Comment: @phresnel could you explain why I can't just run the Makefile? It seems like bash code right?

Comment: @Mark: Dammit, because it is not a bash script and if you knew bash scripts well you could see it isn't one. Do some basic research before asking questions like this. You have not a single time opened up your search engine ... You throw a stranger's makefile at us in expectation to get some labour for free ... Budger.

Comment: @phresnel why isn't this bash? its sure looks like bash syntax

Comment: @Mark: Regardless of the conclusion you have leapt to, it's _not_ Bash syntax at all. It is a Makefile.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal alright I will read more into that

Comment: @Mark: In order to read "more" into something, it is necessary to have read _anything about it_ in the first place.

Comment: Lets keep comments constructive. I'm not closing this as it is on topic and answerable. @Mark - Please, if you solicit advice from your peers, it's _quite polite_ to accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use the `make` command to run the Makefile. you can specify a target for make, like `make all`.

Answer (score 2):

Don't execute the makefile on its own. Your shell is trying to treat it as a shell script of some kind.

Run `make`, which *uses* the makefile.

Comment: Why can't I use Makefile on its own? It looks like bash code to me.

Comment: @Mark: So you admit you have not a single time tried to understand or research the concept behind makefiles, but throw it at us code-monkeys expecting to fulfill your work?

Comment: @Mark: Well, it is not. It is a makefile.